# MySQL multiple group on a single field to generate combinations

Tags: mysql, group-by, combinations

I have a table like this

| Id_Product | Id_Option | Group | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | qty | text1 |
| 1 | 2 | qty | text2 |
| 1 | 3 | qty | text3 |
| 1 | 4 | size | text4 |
| 1 | 5 | size | text5 |
| 1 | 6 | weigth | text6 |

I need to find a way to find all the possibles combinaisons from the group field

Example

| Id_Product | Id_Option1 | qty | Id_Option2 | size | Id_Option3 | weigth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | text1 | 4 | text4 | 6 | text6 |
| 1 | 1 | text1 | 5 | text5 | 6 | text6 |
| 1 | 2 | text1 | 4 | text4 | 6 | text6 |
| 1 | 2 | text1 | 5 | text4 | 6 | text6 |
| 1 | 3 | text1 | 4 | text4 | 6 | text6 |
| 1 | 3 | text1 | 5 | text4 | 6 | text6 |

The number of different record for the group column for different id_product may vary

So far I am doing it in php with multiples query but there must be a cleaner way to do it in mysql directly.

Doing this short algo so far

- Select distinct Id_Product as The_Product from table order by Id_Product
- Select disctinct table.group as The_Group from table where Id_Product = The_Product
- Select Count(Id_Option) as Nb_Variant from table

From the Nb_Variant, I populate an array and end up getting the data, but this takes so much query and memory as there is over 100k records in that table.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the list of possible values in `Group` column is fixed with shown 3 values and won't be changed in future? If not then this is dynamic PIVOT which needs in stored procedure and dynamic SQL.

Comment: Group is a lousy name for a column

Comment: It is not possible for a query to have a variable number of columns.

Comment: the "group" name is demonstrative here and yes it can actually have different number of pairs. Was thinking about maybe populate some temp tables then merge it